# How to create my Python3 automation program useable by another users?

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications, portable-applications

Right now I can create a simple Ms.Excel automation program using Python3 but I want to others can also use my program. 
What kind of features or packages that I could learn to make others able to use my program? Such as turn my program into portable software or web application?

Comment: Hi, I personally think that your question is a bit too broad. Could you narrow it down to a more comprehensive question? Also some code or snippet could be very helpful for people to better help you out!

Comment: for short, I have lines of codes that can automate my ms.excel task. And I want to make a software who runs my code so my friend can use it easily

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into packaging your python application with all its dependedncies. Pyinstaller is a good way to go you can find a very good tutorial [here](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/).

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll try it.

Comment: Okay if this answer was helpful remember to mark it as the correct answer